# Do I need to set a regular job that cleans up the local file system if I use staging S3A committers?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, s3a-committers

I was reading "a zero rename committer" pdf from https://github.com/steveloughran/zero-rename-committer/releases

Sometimes I don't understand things written there, so, just wanted to make sure.

If I use Spark with staging committers, do I need to set up something like cron jobs that regularly clean up localTaskAttempt directories on each node? Because these directories don't get cleaned up, except for those that are located on the same node, where the cleanupJob method is run.

So, those directories, after a Spark job has completed are left there regardless of whether the job succeeded or not, correct?